# When is Taylor series a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, recurrence-relations

We [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) that Taylor series is a rational function if and only if its coefficients satisfy the linear recurrence relation.

Can we put further conditions on the coefficients so that the Taylor series is a polynomial?

Comment: All but finitely many coefficients must be $0$.

Comment: they are zero past a certain point

Comment: Iff the function is a polynomial !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Taylor series is a polynomial iff it has finitely many non-zero coefficients, by definition of polynomials.

Comment: I don't understand why the answer given @MM8 has been erased by its author. It was THE good answer.